# Injectivity of the Abel map away from singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

It is known that a smooth projective curve $C$ of genus $\geq 1$ over $\mathbb{C}$ embeds into its Jacobian $J(C)$, via the isomorphism $J(C) \cong \mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$.

**Question 1.** Is this embedding still true over a number field?

We identify two distinct points $P_1,P_2$ on $C$ to obtain a nodal curve $X$. This is a singular projective curve with node $Q$ and we obtain an exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m \rightarrow J(X) \rightarrow J(C) \rightarrow 0,$$
where $J(X) \rightarrow J(C)$ is the *pullback map* induced by the normalization $C \rightarrow X$. The variety $J(X)$ is called the *generalized Jacobian* with respect to the modulus $\mathfrak{m} = P_1+P_2$. It is not a proper variety, and $C \rightarrow J(X)$ is a rational map regular away from $\{P_1,P_2\}$.

**Question 2.** Does the affine curve $X\backslash \{Q\}$ embed into $J(X)$?

Comment: Question 1:  To define the Abel-Jacobi map, you need a divisor $D$ of degree 1 — then you map a closed point $p$ to the class of the divisor $[p]-D$. If your curve is defined over a field $k$, you need $D$ to be defined over $k$. Then yes, of course, the Abel map is an embedding, since it becomes an embedding over $\bar{k}.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $


Question 2: Yes, $X\smallsetminus Q$ embeds into $JX$, exactly in the same way.

Comment: @abx For question 1, I suppose we can conveniently choose $D$ to be the distinguished $k$-rational point. As for question 2, even if I was to identify $n+1$ points as $Q$ and obtain an exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{G}^n_m \rightarrow J(X) \rightarrow J(C) \rightarrow 0,$$ the map $X \backslash \{Q\} \rightarrow J(X)$ is still defined the same way right? Or are there things to take note in the general case of identifying $n \geq 2$ points together?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are considering smooth points things are exactly as in the case of a smooth curve.